# How to import target dataset to deep network designer?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, target

I designed a deep network using deep network designer in Matlab. I already imported the input dataset. and I want to import the target data ( every target is an image or a matrix). Does anyone know how to load the target data into the deep network designer? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "nnstart" you can upload the target data set (see Dynamic Time series > NARX).